# How to send message back and forth using RPC (msdn) in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, rpc, idl

I am trying to write an RPC server application and an RPC client application in order to send messages back and forth.

I could send a message from the client to the server successfully by following this tutorial:   https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4837/Introduction-to-RPC-Part-1. Now modified the code so that server can send a response back as well to the client.

Here is my IDL file:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";
[
    // A unique identifier that distinguishes this
    // interface from other interfaces.
    uuid(00000001-EAF3-4A7A-A0F2-BCE4C30DA77E),

    // This is version 1.0 of this interface.
    version(1.0),

    // This interface will use an implicit binding
    // handle named hExample1Binding.
    implicit_handle(handle_t hExample1Binding)
]
interface Example1 // The interface is named Example1
{
    // A function that takes a zero-terminated string.
    void Output(
        [in, string] const char* szInput,
        [out, string, size_is(500)] const char* szOutput);
}
```

Here is my server code:

```
// PlainRPCServer.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"



// File ContextExampleServer.cpp

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Example1_h.h"

using namespace std;

// Server function.
void Output(
    /* [string][in] */ const unsigned char *szInput,
    /* [size_is][string][out] */ const unsigned char *szOutput)
{
    std::cout << "from client " << szInput << std::endl;
    szOutput = "Reply from the server";
    return;
}

// Naive security callback.
RPC_STATUS CALLBACK SecurityCallback(RPC_IF_HANDLE /*hInterface*/, void* /*pBindingHandle*/)
{
    return RPC_S_OK; // Always allow anyone.
}

int main()
{
    RPC_STATUS status;

    // Uses the protocol combined with the endpoint for receiving
    // remote procedure calls.
    status = RpcServerUseProtseqEpA(
        (RPC_CSTR)("ncacn_ip_tcp"), // Use TCP/IP protocol.
        RPC_C_PROTSEQ_MAX_REQS_DEFAULT, // Backlog queue length for TCP/IP.
        (RPC_CSTR)("4747"),         // TCP/IP port to use.
        NULL);                          // No security.

    if (status)
        exit(status);

    // Registers the Example1 interface.
    status = RpcServerRegisterIf2(
        Example1_v1_0_s_ifspec,              // Interface to register.
        NULL,                                // Use the MIDL generated entry-point vector.
        NULL,                                // Use the MIDL generated entry-point vector.
        RPC_IF_ALLOW_CALLBACKS_WITH_NO_AUTH, // Forces use of security callback.
        RPC_C_LISTEN_MAX_CALLS_DEFAULT,      // Use default number of concurrent calls.
        (unsigned)-1,                        // Infinite max size of incoming data blocks.
        SecurityCallback);                   // Naive security callback.

    if (status)
        exit(status);

    // Start to listen for remote procedure
    // calls for all registered interfaces.
    // This call will not return until
    // RpcMgmtStopServerListening is called.
    status = RpcServerListen(
        1,                                   // Recommended minimum number of threads.
        RPC_C_LISTEN_MAX_CALLS_DEFAULT,      // Recommended maximum number of threads.
        FALSE);                              // Start listening now.

    if (status)
        exit(status);
}

// Memory allocation function for RPC.
// The runtime uses these two functions for allocating/deallocating
// enough memory to pass the string to the server.
void* __RPC_USER midl_user_allocate(size_t size)
{
    return malloc(size);
}

// Memory deallocation function for RPC.
void __RPC_USER midl_user_free(void* p)
{
    free(p);
}
```

The server is running with this code. However, as the client is not working I am not sure whether the server is working correctly.

This is my client's code:

```
// PlainRPCClient.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Example1_h.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    RPC_STATUS status;
    RPC_CSTR szStringBinding = NULL;

    // Creates a string binding handle.
    // This function is nothing more than a printf.
    // Connection is not done here.
    status = RpcStringBindingComposeA(
        NULL,                                        // UUID to bind to.
        (RPC_CSTR)("ncacn_ip_tcp"),// Use TCP/IP protocol.
        (RPC_CSTR)("localhost"),   // TCP/IP network address to use.
        (RPC_CSTR)("4747"),        // TCP/IP port to use.
        NULL,                                    // Protocol dependent network options to use.
        &szStringBinding);                       // String binding output.

    if (status)
        exit(status);

    // Validates the format of the string binding handle and converts
    // it to a binding handle.
    // Connection is not done here either.
    status = RpcBindingFromStringBindingA(
        szStringBinding,        // The string binding to validate.
        &hExample1Binding);     // Put the result in the implicit binding
                                // handle defined in the IDL file.

    if (status)
        exit(status);

    RpcTryExcept
    {
        // Calls the RPC function. The hExample1Binding binding handle
        // is used implicitly.
        // Connection is done here.
        const unsigned char* serverMsg = NULL;
        Output((const unsigned char *)"msg from the client", serverMsg);
    }
        RpcExcept(1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Runtime reported exception " << RpcExceptionCode()
            << std::endl;
    }
    RpcEndExcept

        // Free the memory allocated by a string.
        status = RpcStringFreeA(
            &szStringBinding); // String to be freed.

    if (status)
        exit(status);

    // Releases binding handle resources and disconnects from the server.
    status = RpcBindingFree(
        &hExample1Binding); // Frees the implicit binding handle defined in the IDL file.

    if (status)
        exit(status);
}

// Memory allocation function for RPC.
// The runtime uses these two functions for allocating/deallocating
// enough memory to pass the string to the server.
void* __RPC_USER midl_user_allocate(size_t size)
{
    return malloc(size);
}

// Memory deallocation function for RPC.
void __RPC_USER midl_user_free(void* p)
{
    free(p);
}
```

My client code terminates with: **Runtime reported exception 1780**

NB: I am using VS2015(incase it matters).

My questions:

1. Calling the remote method "output" from the client has issues but I can not figure it. The reason for **serverMsg = NULL** can be found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rpc/idl-techniques-for-better-interface-and-method-design (The client application component must set ppStr(for my code it's serverMsg) to NULL on when calling the RPC method.)
2. How to send the message back to the client from the server? I couldn't find this example in MSDN. (For now, I just did this: **szOutput = "Reply from the server"** in the server code)
3. And how to handle the received message in the client application? (I mean how to assign the message and work with it in the client)?

Comment: Are you aware of the [callback] IDL attribute? That should enable two-way communication. (Only from within a server-side implementation unless you go to explicit binding handles).

Comment: You need to establish two communication channels and open two ports between the communication parties, which is cumbersome and inelegant.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Yes, I am aware of explicit binding but not sure how to write code in the server-side for returning some value.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT  Where can I find a proper example? Any idea? In Microsoft document they just provide few lines. Didn't find any example showing how the server communicates back with the client.

Comment: Maybe your Google search with "c++ Bi-directional RPC" as the keyword will have new discoveries.